# eclipse xtext - restructure package hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, xtext

I have restructured my xtext project packages from `com.x.y` to `com.x.y.z`.
But unfortunately not all the path references got updated.

To run the mwe2 workflow seems to be no problem. But the `src-gen` folders get generated still in the former (`com.x.y`) hierarchy.

Some path entries in the plugin.xml (both `com.x.y.z`and `com.x.y.z.ui`) got ignored to update. So i tried to change them manuelly. But it still doesn't work.

Could someone give me a suggestion where in an xtext project, are the correct path configurations, to tell the compile, in which order the `src-gen` folders get generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also restructured the grammars of the EMF-IncQuery project about a year ago. I don't remember exactly what was needed to manage the generation into the new package, but one of the following had to do the trick:

1. We have moved the mwe and xtext files into a new package.

   1. This meant, we had to update the grammarURI property in the MWE
2. We have updated the grammar/ecore uri to be similar to the new naming convention.

All our changes are available in our old repository (https://github.com/ujhelyiz/EMF-IncQuery/commit/6f7a618fc7f89386c9f85b3481761168ea91857a), but I cannot provide a smaller example. You might want to look for the Xtext, MWE, and possibly manifest changes.

Comment: Thanks for you advices. My project went worse and worse. I couldn't fix it an more. So i decieded to set up a complete new one.